# How to interpret Bayesian evidence greater than 1?

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, posterior

The Bayesian model evidence/ denominator of posterior sometimes could be way bigger than 1, which means the probability of observing a certain value under a hypothesis. How to interpret the meaning of evidence?

Comment: Obviously a value of $1$ is not a probability.  That indicates you should take a closer look at exactly how your "model evidence/denominator of posterior" is computed and what it represents.  I suspect the thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220 might be relevant.

Comment: If I understand correctly, do you mean that P(data|model(i)) is a continuous distribution with the variable model(i)? @whuber

Comment: I don't mean anything specific because that aspect of your question is too vague for anyone but you to know what it refers to.  I'm only guessing about the circumstances that might be motivating your reference to a value "way bigger than 1" as a "probability."